# Determine MIME type of a file while opening in browser using c++ and browser helper object

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, browser, mime-types, bho

when i click a link on browser which opens a file (. PDFs ,.doc,....) how to find the mime type of that file which is getting opened using browser helper object? i am new please help me 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [install a PassThru App and read the HTTP header](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control). Then you can parse the header text to get the MIME type, and [good luck with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding).

Comment: no i want to achieve it through c++ or visualc++ not through any of tools

Comment: a pass thru app is a plugin you need to write, it is not a tool ready for use.