# Apache Unicode AuthName strings?

Tags: apache, unicode, apache2

I added a username and password for a basic authentication on Apache, and I want to have Unicode AuthName strings to my users. My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Some Unicode Here"
    AuthUserFile /somewhere/htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

But "`Some Unicode Here`" always appears to be garbage in my browser. How do I make it appear properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not be able to make it work, lack of browser support is the main issue, see [What character encoding should I use for a HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding).
The `AuthName` appears as the realm in the `WWW-Authenticate` header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Some Unicode Here"
```

Some quick experimentation shows:

- Apache does not encode a UTF-8 `AuthName` string in the config, it sends it as-is
- Firefox, MSIE and Chrome all (correctly) interpret that UTF-8 byte sequence as ISO-8859-1 (and hence likely display it incorrectly)
- none support RFC-2047 MIME encoding as stated by HTTP RFC-2616, the display it literally as `=?utf-8?B?U29tZSBVbmljb2RlIEhlcmUK?=`

(I suggest `mod_auth_tkt` as cookie-based a replacement for basic auth if you have the option, it has a drop-in htpasswd style perl script, and sets `REMOTE_USER`, you just need to roll your own form.)

Answer (score 3):

I have found a proper solution for .htaccess AuthName containing accentuated characters :

**Save the file in the correct encoding using your text editor or "iconv".**

In Sublime 3, I used the File -> Save with Encoding -> Western ISO-8859-1

Comment: This works and allows you to keep using mod_auth_basic.