# UTF-8 in AuthName message

Tags: apache2

How would one make the following .htaccess works (French):

```
AuthName "Page protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

The file is properly written in UTF-8, but it looks like only epiphany browser is capable of displaying this UTF-8 message.

I have tried so far setting in httpd.conf:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

without no effect at all.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494701/apache-unicode-authname-strings