# Special character in cookies in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I'm saving an Array Json in cookies from server with something like this:

> HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies["ProcessArray"];
>
> myCookie.Value = JSONC.Serialize(lstProcess);

and in Chrome I'm getting this (with javascript):

> document.cookie
>
> "ProcessArray=[{"ProcessID":1,"Description":"Adquisición de Articulos","Path":"internalprocess.aspx?process=1"}]"

but in IE (8,9,10) I'm getting this:

> document.cookie
>
> "ProcessArray=[{"ProcessID":1,"Description":"AdquisiciÃ³n de
> Articulos","Path":"internalprocess.aspx?process=1"}]"

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ã³` is the UTF-8 encoded version of `ó`

My guess is your JSON serializer is converting to UTF-8.  Maybe that can output ISO-8859-1 instead? (see [What is the difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1))

If you are setting the cookie via a `Set-Cookie` HTTP Header (vs. in JavaScript), IE probably handles this different that Chrome.  (see [HTTP header should use what character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding))

**Update:**  EricLaw's comment is correct about using US-ASCII.  I think [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) is the best reference on this, where it introduces "encoded word" for character sets other than US-ASCII.

However, in this particular example, instead of using encoded word or %XX URL encoding, this cookie value is JSON, so I would use the JavaScript string escape sequence (see [Special Characters (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)).  `ó` is character 0xF3 so use the string `'\u00F3'` in your JSON formatted cookie value.  This allows any client side cookie reads, to just JSON.parse() the value.

> document.cookie
>
> "ProcessArray=[{"ProcessID":1,"Description":"Adquisici\u00F3n de
> Articulos","Path":"internalprocess.aspx?process=1"}]"

Comment: For interoperability, HTTP headers should always be pure ASCII. Use %-UTF8 encoding on the cookie name/value before storing it to the headers.

Comment: @EricLaw - I knew that, but forgot - thanks for reminding me.  I updated the answer with more correct info.