# AJAX - what is the default character-encoding for HTTP header values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, character-encoding

For example, suppose I'm using AJAX to send a request to a server like so:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function (request) { request.setRequestHeader('X-Test', 'one'); },
    });
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for `$.ajax` contains the following:

> **contentType** (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8') **Type**: String
>
> When sending data to the server, use this
>   content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass
>   in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server
>   (even if no data is sent). The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification
>   dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset
>   will not force the browser to change the encoding.

According to this, the default is UTF-8, but I'm not clear from the description if the `contentType` header affects only the encoding of the request's body or the encoding of the other headers as well (if the latter can even be changed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP header should use what character encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contentType only affects the body/document.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding) you can use any ISO-8859-1 characters in the header.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that AJAX render part of the HTML body, so when you send data in a AJAX request with some content type, for example iso-8859-1, the data is setting with that content type only in the AJAX request life cycle.

I hope my answer be useful for you.

Good lucky.