# Is it appropriate or necessary to use percent-encoding with HTTP Headers?

Tags: rest, http

When I'm building RESTful client and servers, is it appropriate or necessary to use [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) with HTTP Headers (request or response), or does this type of encoding just apply to URIs?

Comment: Take a look yourself, RFC 2616 is the most important definition for the http protocol: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP header should use what character encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP header should use what character encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically No, but see below.

[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) describes percent-encoding only for URIs (search for `%` or `HEX HEX` or `percent`) and it defines the `field-value` without mentioning percent-encoding.

However, RFC2616 allows arbitraty octets (except `CTL`s) in the header field value, and has a half-baked statement mentioning MIME encoding (RFC2047) for characters not in ISO-8859-1 (see definition of `TEXT` in its [Section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2)). I called that statement "half-baked" because it does not exlictly state that ISO-8859-1 is the mandatory character set to be used for interpreting the octets, but despite of that, it normatively requires the use of MIME encoding for characters outside of that character set. It seems that both the use of ISO-8859-1 and the MIME encoding of header field values are not widely supported.

HTTPbis seems to have given up on this, and goes back to US-ASCII for header field values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410331/1424462) for details.

My reading of this is:

- For standard header fields (those defined in RFC2616), percent-encoding is not permitted.
- For extension header fields, percent-encoding is not described in RFC2616, but there is room for applying all kinds of encodings, including percent-encoding, as long as the resulting characters are US-ASCII (if you want to be future-proof). Just don't think you *have* to use percent-encoding.

Some more sources I found:

- https://www.quora.com/Do-HTTP-headers-need-to-be-encoded confirms my understanding, although it is not specific about standard headers vs extension headers and does not quote a source.
- https://support.ca.com/us/knowledge-base-articles.TEC1904612.html argues that the percent-encoding of extension headers in their product is a measure of protection against CSS attacks.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer for now since it fairly concisely answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Octet percent-encoding and base64 encoding are fine.

Indicating Character Encoding and Language for HTTP Header Field Parameters
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8187

> This document specifies an encoding suitable for use in HTTP header
> fields...

Read the "3.2.3. Examples"

*base64* encoding is fine too, as read the HTTP Basic Authorziation spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617

Comment: Note that all of this only applies to header fields that specifically allow these kind of escape mechanisms.