# Why do need metadata information specifying the encoding?

Tags: web, encoding, utf-8, httprequest

I feel a bit of a chicken and egg problem if i write a html meta tag specifying charset as say `UTF-16` - like how do we decode the entire HTTP Request in the first place if we didn't know its `UTF-16 data` ? I believe request header needs to handle this and by the time we try to read metadata like say html tag `charset="utf-16"` we already know its `UTF-16` . 
Besides think one level higher about header information like Request Headers - are passed in ASCII as a standard ?

I mean at some level we need to agree upon and you can't set a data that is needed to decode as a metadata information . Can anyone clarify this ?
I am a bit confused on the idea of specifying a data that is needed to interpret the whole data as a metadata information inside the original data .

In general how can any form of encoding work if we don't have a standard agreed upon language/encoding to convey the data about the data itself ?

For example I am informed that Apache default has `8859-1` as the standard . So would all client need to enforce that for HTTP Headers and interpret the real content as `UTF-8` if we want `UTF-8` for the `content-type` ?

[What character encoding should I use for a HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/http-header-should-use-what-character-encoding) is a closely related question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-16 (and other) encodings use a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that is read at the start of the file and that signals which encoding is being used. Only after that, the encoded part of the file begins.

For example, for UTF-16, you'll have the bytes `FE FF` if big-endian and `FF FE` if little-endian words are being used.

You also often see UTF-8 BOMs, although they don't need to be used (and may confuse some XML parsers).

Comment: So what is the standard these days? I mean do browsers and apache agree to use UTF-8 for anything everything these days or is it like Headers continue with 8859-1 and yet the real content is expected to be encoded as UTF-8 if its set to UTF-8 or even as default ?

Comment: @Nishant: UTF-8 is a single-byte encoding, and it encloses ASCII as a subset, so the line where the encoding is declared is actually in ASCII. Save your file as UTF-8, and make sure to declare the encoding at its start.

Comment: When you say file which file do you mean ? Static HTML is hard used these days . All that we deal wit dynamic right ? And to get the file browser has to make a Request first which I guess is LATIN as per the Web Server configuration - which I am assuming has a standard that browser adheres to - otherwise some browser might not open some sites . Can you clarify - also helpful if you can answer as part of the original answer because that is one of the questions I have .

Comment: The HTTP header has priority. If it says a particular charset, that is the charset used. The HTTP 1.1 spec requires that. If there is no HTTP header charset, the HTML header charset is used, if specified. Without a BOM or an HTTP header charset, a single-byte charset must be assumed so the HTML header can be parsed to discover its charset (as long as the HTML really is single byte encoded, otherwise a BOM or an HTTP header charset MUST be used).