# nginx file upload with client_body_in_file_only

Tags: nginx, file-upload

Good evening,
I need to upload static content to nginx server 1.9 (so upload module didn't work with this version). I've read the article ["Nginx direct file upload without passing them through backend"](https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw/nginx-direct-file-upload-without-passing-them-through-backend) and followed instructions step by step. Everything works for me, except file names at the nginx data directory. File names look like '0000000001', '0061565403' and so on. **What should I do to save files with their correct names?**
Here is my nginx location config:

```
location /upload {
limit_except POST              { deny all; }
client_body_temp_path          /data/;
client_body_in_file_only       on;
client_body_buffer_size        128K;
client_max_body_size           50M;
proxy_pass_request_headers     on;
proxy_set_header content-type "text/html";
proxy_set_body                 $request_body_file;
proxy_pass                     http://localhost:8080/
proxy_redirect                 off;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTTP header in the client to pass the correct name (whatever that is), e.g.:

```
Correct-Filename: my-correct-filename
```

And since you're using `proxy_pass_request_headers on`, the header is visible in the back end where you can use it when saving the file. However when using headers the filename is limited to using ASCII characters, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-http-header/4410331#4410331).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to do this is to send the original filename as a parameter (I use JS to copy the filename to a hidden field), and then, on the server, if I am storing the temp file to our file system, I use that parameter to rename the file in the process of saving it to its "proper" location.

Not beautiful, but it works.

Comment: Do you have any example?