# nginx upload file and change its name

Tags: nginx, file-upload

I use next config to save files on nginx. It works fine but filenames becomes like 0000001234. Is there a way to change filenames to original?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429470/nginx-file-upload-with-client-body-in-file-only/60883328) is the same question, the reply suggests to use additional header with original filename but there's no clear answer how to use it and how to rename the file.

```
  limit_except POST          { deny all; }

  client_body_temp_path      /www/sitename/uploads;
  client_body_in_file_only   on;
  client_body_buffer_size    128K;
  client_max_body_size       100000M;

  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;

  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file;
  proxy_set_body             off;
  proxy_redirect             off;
  proxy_pass                 http://farm1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not supported as a module

- https://github.com/fdintino/nginx-upload-module/issues/69
- https://serverfault.com/questions/475755/nginx-upload-module-and-file-names