# Retrieving an encoded value from HTTP Header java

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

In my spring webapp I am receiving an HTTP header with RC4 encrypted string. When I decrypt this after taking the value from header I am getting wrong string. Following is the code excerpts from spring controller class.What is the default decoding done in the request.getheader() method. how can I use any other decoding?

Following is the tcp trace screenshot showing header key and value.

[image: screenshot of tcptrace]

```
byte[] enc_msisdn = request.getHeader(headerName).getBytes();
rc4 = new RC4("rc4pskey".getBytes());
byte[] decipher = rc4.decrypt(enc_msisdn);
```

Comment: Is your actual key representable in 7-bit ASCII? If not, you might have character encoding issues because you aren't explicitly specifying the charset.

Comment: Thanks Andy.the value i want to retriev from header wil be something like this " sN vÎÙÀ¸ëÝV ". How can i explicitly specify which decoding to use while taking value from getHeader() method.

Comment: (That's an outrageous value for a HTTP header.)  You may want to try `ISO-8859-1` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-http-header#4410331.  Failing that, UTF-8 may be worth trying too.  Any knowledge that you have of the source of the request might give you further ideas to try.

Comment: unfortunately yes. We are using this to get the RC4 encrypted value of mobile number for security reason. I am updating my question with screenshot showing  the value i can see in the tcp trace. Appreciate your support.

Comment: For what it's worth, `iconv` accepts the sequence as `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: So,is there any way to UTF-8 decode the header value string in java with the **request** object?