# send emoji in http header ionic2

Tags: javascript, http, ionic2, emoji

I am not able to send emoji in HTTP header though emoji is a plain text.
Error is emoji is not a valid HTTP header field value.

```
createStatus(user: any, status: any) {
    let that = this;
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('token', user.accessToken);
    headers.set('facebookId', user.facebookId);
    headers.set('operation', 'create');
    headers.set('status', status);

    return that.http.post(Constants.API_URL + '/post', {}, {headers: headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(that.handleError);
  }
```

Please tell me what  I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where is the emoji header in your code?

Comment: If some one put emoji in the status input field and save it, then the error is showing that emoji is not a valid HTTP header field value. How can i put a emoji header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For HTTP header value, only ASCII characters are guaranteed to work. Other characters, such as Emoji or Chinese characters won't be allowed by most HTTP client. Please refer to [What character encoding should I use for a HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-http-header) for some previous discussion.

To send Emoji in HTTP request, there are 2 methods:

1. Encode Emoji character and send it as header. For example:

   ```
   var status = encodeURIComponent('⌛'); // %E2%8C%9B
   headers.set('status', status);
   ```

   When the request is received in server, decode it:

   ```
   var statusValEncoded = '%E2%8C%9B';
   var statusVal = decodeURIComponent(statusValEncoded); // ⌛
   ```
2. Send Emoji character as request body. For example:

   ```
   that.http.post(Constants.API_URL + '/post', {status: '⌛'}, {headers: headers})
   ```